# Converting object of type Any into myClass, by passing the myClass as parameter

Tags: scala

So I have a class:

```
case class Document (idx: String, name: String, code: String)
```

Due to some transformations, an object which was initially created as Document, now becomes of type Any.

```
val doc = Document("12", "anyName", "ps") // Ends up as type Any
```

So I want to convert it into type `Document` again.

I know that can be done like this:

```
val docNew = doc.asInstanceOf[Document]
```

But, what I am trying is to pass the type, in this case `Document`, as a parameter to make it more generic.

So I was trying the following:

```
val mType = Document
val docNew = doc.asInstanceOf[mType]
```

But Intellij says:

> Cannot resolve symbol mType

Edit: My ultimate goal is to pass the parameter `Document` to a function, so at the end I could do something like:

```
def convertIntoDoc(doc: Any, mType: Type) = {
    val docNew = doc.asInstanceOf[mType]
    docNew
}
```

Comment: Your actual problem is that you somehow ended up with an `Any` when you are sure it's actually an `mType`. If you can be sure so should be the compiler.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

instead of `val` you can use `type`

```
type mType = Document
val docNew = doc.asInstanceOf[mType]
```

For the second part of the question, you can pass the type using type parameter as argument

```
def convertIntoDoc[A](doc: Any) = {
    val docNew = doc.asInstanceOf[A]
    docNew
}
```

Comment: Thanks actually that solved my problem as I have it in the question. Could you enrich the answer with the case you pass the type as a parameter of a function. I will edit answer with a second part. And thanks for your time

Comment: This is not a good answer, as explained in @Markus Appel's answer

Comment: @Lasf Hi, actually this answer gave me the solution for my initial problem with asInstanceOf. However it is true Markus later enrich the answer with further information.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to learn programming with Scala you have to learn about the difference between *types* and *values*.

Due to type-erasure type parameters never actually make it into your program. In reality, types only exist to help you write good code.

If you go down this road you will eventually realise that `asInstanceOf[T]` does not actually do *anything*.

You might think this is weird and with type-erasure the type system is superfluous, but let me assure you it is perfectly useful and when it comes to more complicated code actually becomes the stepping stone to *generic programming*, e.g. code that can be used in many different ways due to type parametrisation.

To spin this a little further you should almost never end up with a `val` of type `Any` because you will loose this additional safety net of static typing. This means you have already made a mistake somewhere upstream in your code.

Your ultimate goal is simple to achieve:

```
def convertIntoDoc[MType](doc: Any) = {
    val docNew = doc.asInstanceOf[MType]
    docNew
}
```

You just have to remember that `MType` is a type and not a variable. So it has to be used as type parameter and not as value parameter.

The problem is that casting an `Any` into a `MType` will get you `ClassCastException`s (when running your program!) if you use the wrong type.

`asInstanceOf` is very dangerous because it kind of overwrites the type safety that the Scala compiler provides.

If you have any questions about this let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will check then in what step I am converting the object into Any, to start with. And I will add you in any further question I may ask about this topic.

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre Good idea. I will be happy to help.

Comment: It is not right to say that "types never actually make it into your program": Type erasure only applies to type parameters.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to convert your `Any` to `Document` is to use `match`:

```
val docNew = doc match { case d: Document => d }
```

This is safe because it will throw a `MatchException` if for some reason the object is not of type `Document`.

Your `convertIntoDoc` function is just a wrapper around `asInstanceOf`, so you need to give more detail on what this function is intended to do (preferably in a separate question).

Comment: Thanks Tim, I will try also that thing you mention and come up with a more complex question of what is what I ultimately want to achieve, since it is a little bit long and I tried to make a simple question, but see it wasn't enough